# Data-binding via Dart web-ui in a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, dart-webui

I'm trying to use two-way data-binding to a Dart variable inside a Bootstrap Popover with no success. My code looks something like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Popup</title>        

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
      <button type="button" id="constcon-options-button" class="btn" title="Options" rel="popover" data-html="true" data-content="
        <div id='constcon-options-form' class='form-horizontal'>
           <input type='radio' name='veggies' value='kale' bind-value='veg'>
             Kale<br>
           <input type='radio' name='veggies' value='spinach' bind-value='veg'>
             Spinach<br>
           <input type='radio' name='veggies' value='carrots' bind-value='veg'>
             Carrots
        </div>">Options
      </button>

      <p>veg = {{veg}}</p>

      <script type='application/dart'>

        import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
        import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

        @observable
        String veg = 'spinach'; // Sets an initial value. Button with 
                                // value == 'spinach' is auto-selected.
        void main() {
          js.scoped(() 
          { 
            js.context.jQuery("#constcon-options-button").popover();                      
          });
        }

      </script>    

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="resources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>       

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This all works OK in a Bootstrap Modal (or anywhere else for that matter) but doesn't update the variable/radio buttons when in a Popover. I assume this is because the HTML is contained within the data-content="..." attribute and thus doesn't get processed by web-ui.

Is there any other way I can get data-binding working in a Bootstrap popover?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-html="true"` in your button.

### [Popover demo with HTML](http://bootply.com/61237)

Comment: No, it's not that. Sorry - forgot to mention that I already set this in code elsewhere.

Comment: OK - I have modified my original question to contatin a complete code sample. As it stands, the "veg" variable is not modified when the radio buttons are changed. If the radios are moved out of the popover, it all works as expected.